# Inspecting values at runtime in classic ASP with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I like that Visual Studio 2008 SP1 supports debugging and breakpoints in classic ASP/VBScript, but I'm trying to inpsect values of objects at runtime (by hovering the mouse over while stepping through).  This used to work, even in classic ASP, but it seems to have stopped working for me.  Does anyone know if there's a specific setting to enable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIS console --> Website properties --> `Virtual Directory` tab --> `Configuration` button --> `Debugging` tab --> "Enable ASP server side script debugging" --> tick and confirm.

Comment: Yeah, done that, but it still won't show any metadata at runtime when I hover the cursor over objects.  I guess I can use the Locals watch window, but I was wondering what has caused this to stop working...

Comment: @tus dunno, maybe local Visual Studio glitch.. if you have `.ncb` file try deleting it (when studio is closed) and see if it helps.